# Arrays are being filled with null instead of names and 0 instead of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, file, null

I need to fill the two seperate arrays with the names from a text file and corresponding account balances.
The file looks like this

```
10
Helene 1000
Jordan 755
Eve 2500
Ken 80
Andrew 999
David 1743
Amy 12
Sean 98
Patrick 7
Joy 14
```

where 10 is the number of accounts

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class bankaccountmain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner inFile = null;
        try {
            inFile = new Scanner(new File("account.txt"));
            ;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");

            System.exit(0);
        }
        int count = 0;
        int accounts = inFile.nextInt();
        String[] names = new String[accounts];
        int[] balance = new int[accounts];
        while (inFile.hasNextInt()) {
            inFile.next();
            names[count] = inFile.next();
            inFile.nextInt();
            balance[count] = inFile.nextInt();
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(balance));
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `hasNextInt` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is poorly defined.

You are checking to see if there is a next int instead of a next token, and consuming lines you don't intend to.

Try this as a loop instead:

```
    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        names[count] = inFile.next();
        balance[count] = inFile.nextInt();
        count++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the loop as follows.  Change the while() clause and comment out the 2 lines.

```
    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        //inFile.next();
        names[count] = inFile.next();
        //inFile.nextInt();
        balance[count] = inFile.nextInt();
        count++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
int accounts = inFile.nextInt();
```

consumes this token

```
10
```

You then do

```
while (inFile.hasNextInt()) {
```

but the next tokens in the file are

```
\nHelene 1000
```

so the method call will return `false` since there is no next `int` and the loop will exit.

Perhaps you should check for full lines.